# How to access Virtual Machine in LAN with proxy

Tags: windows, proxy, virtual-machines, local-area-network, vmware-workstation

I have setup a website in a virtual machine running in VMWare Workstation (Trial).

I need to access that website in our LAN network. But there is a proxy on our the LAN.
When I try to access the website on Host machine without proxy, it works. But with proxy it does not access the VM website. But without proxy I can't access the website from other machines inside the network.

How can I achieve that?

**Note: I don't have any control over LAN and proxy configuration.**

Answer (score 1):

If you have no control over the Proxy, try not using it for local addresses.

[image]

If that doesn't work, or poses other problems, you can specify the IP by clicking on 'Advanced'.

[image]

**However**, you should never attempt to run a service, somewhere on a network without notifying/asking the network admins. In most companies, this is a fireable offense.

And, I'm pretty sure you can't use the trail version to provide a production service.

Comment: Hi @Bart De Vos, I have already tried both of those option. Does not make any difference. Actually its third party service which we are running internally for our initial testing.